# How to unit test UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

I am adding unit tests for a project and am stumbling on how to write tests for a UITableViewCell custom class. Here is the code for the class:

```
class ConfirmSubmitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {
var reportECTag: ReportECTag!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let photoArray = Utility.sharedInstance.getPhotoArray(reportECTag.fieldDataInformationDict)
    return (photoArray.count)
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(kCollectionViewCell, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let imageView: UIImageView = collectionCell.viewWithTag(287) as! UIImageView
    let photoArray = Utility.sharedInstance.getPhotoArray(reportECTag.fieldDataInformationDict)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: (photoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSData)!)//photoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage
    return collectionCell
}
```

For example, how could I test awakeFromNib() and setSelected?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't test a part of the GUI. Can you test the underlying model?

Comment: You are not having any logic in setSelected and awakeFromNib... So its not making any sense to write test